# Powershell Script to capture Disk (C & D) Free Space, Memory Free, CPU usage and Network Utilisiation

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Apologies if this is not in the right area.

I have a list of 200 servers which are a mixture of W2k3 and W2k8 servers which i need to gather the following

C Drive Free Space (in GB)
D Drive Free Space (in Gb)
Memory Free (in GB)
Network Utilisation

I would like to output all data to a csv file for analysis. Ive got all the servers in a text file as well.

Thanks
dw

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: Hi, Ive never wrote a powershell script before. I can see there are scripts elsewhere on this site but they dont quite do what I want and I cant find one which allows multiple servers to be gathered.

Comment: If you're here as a scripter/programmer looking for a solution to a specific problem with your code you've come to that right place.  If you're just wanting a script to perform a specific function, then you probably need a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

To get single measurements you will need to use Powershell workflow to execute the given commands on specific servers in parallel:

```
function disk_free($computer, $disk){
    $s = gwmi -Computer $computer Win32_LogicalDisk | ? DeviceID -eq $disk
    "{0:N2}" -f ($s.FreeSpace*100 / $s.Size)
}

workflow srv_check {   
  param ([array] $computers)   
  foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {
      disk_free $computer "c:"  
      disk_free $computer "d:"
  }
}

$servers=@("srv1", "srv2" ...)      
srv_check -computers $servers
```